# How to make 'select auto_increment' work with mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

Now that I am using mysqli in PHP, the following query doesn't work:

```
"SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table'"
```

Why not, and how can I get it working?

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean? What error do you get when you run it?

Comment: I don't get back anything. but with the old php query command I did!
Does it work for anyone?

Comment: What does `mysqli_error` return?

Comment: oops. ya. ehm. mysqli_error returns "Unknown column 'my_table' in 'where clause'" .. but why column?

Comment: that error implies that the query you're running doesn't have my_table quoted. When MySQL seems an unquoted string like that, it assumes it's a column name.

Comment: right database and correct tablename.. as I told you: the same query worked fine with old php command

Comment: It is quoted with `my_table`, as you can see in the example above

Comment: I've just run that query in my local mysql, and it worked properly, though it didn't return any rows. The only way I could get that error was to leave the quoting off my_table. Also, and I am just being nosy here - is there a reason you need to access the system tables for auto_increment information? I'd've thought there'd be easier ways to get anything you could retrieve from there.

Comment: IS there an easier way?

Comment: If you just performed an insert, you can get its ID with `mysqli::$insert_id`.

Comment: @Barmar - bah, beaten to it while I was looking up the link: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Are you sure you didn't make a transcription error when copying your code to the question? Please cut and paste the actual line from your PHP. Because the error message clearly indicates that `my_table` isn't quoted.

Comment: copy and paste: `echo mysqli_query($this->conn, "SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=DATABASE() AND TABLE_NAME = `my_table`");
  echo mysqli_error($this->conn);`

Comment: seems like stackoverflow uses this quotes for their own stuff

Comment: @JohnDoeSmith - you're using backticks around my_table, not quotes. That's another way you can tell mysql that something is a table name. Swap them out for regular, single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need this query.

If you think you are - there is some critical fault in your database design.
the only proper place for getting autoincremented id is the right next to INSERT query and nowhere else. Otherwise your schema will be subject of race condition and sooner or later will fail you.

So, get you autoincrement only **after** INSERT using `mysqli_insert_id()`